# What is the best way to know Apple Remote Control battery status?

Tags: battery, remote-control, battery-life

Is there any way to know the Apple Remote Control battery status from my Mac OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no indicator in OS X unless you are using an Apple TV.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1722?viewlocale=en_US

Apple wants you to take a digital picture of the remote and see if you can see an IR light pulse from it to check if the battery is dead.

Answer (score 2):

If the battery is getting low, OS 10.5 & 10.6 will flash a picture of the remote, with the battery compartment open to indicate that the battery is low.

This, of course, requires that the remote be able to send a IR signal, so if the remote battery is dead, you'll never see this warning...

See http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1306

Here's a similar picture, but it's not the same picture...

[image]